# WordPress displays every post on 404 error page

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

WordPress version: 4.9.6

404 plugin installed: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/404page/

Page url: https://landhaus-himmelpfort.de/

When I try to visit a non-existing site on my url and get a 404 error, every post is displayed. First I tried to change the 404.php in my theme's folder, than I moved to the 404page plugin (https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/404page/) but nothing helped. I already tried to deactivate all plugin but the issue remained.

My question is: How can I 'install' my own personal 404 page and why does WordPress display all my posts in the current state?

Comment: Goto permalinks and change hat to default and please and let me know

Comment: @Akshay Shah didn't help, also I need custom permalinks for the site

Comment: Are you sure?
Do you call the wp_head() and wp_footer() functions in your header and footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this plugin i think you will solve your 404 page solve..

[this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-404-pro/)

Answer (score 0):

Now after clearing all caches and reinstalling the plugin, it suddenly works.